# OracleCommand cast from DbCommand

Tags: asp.net, oracle

The native oracle provider for .net does not do parameter binding by name as a default so you have to manually set it.

However, in the following code, it is not set UNLESS I replace the line

```
DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
```

with

```
DbConnection conn = OracleClientFactory.Instance.CreateConnection();
```

Following is the full code:

```
 DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
    DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
    using(DbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
       if( command is Oracle.DataAccess.Client )
       {
          ((Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand)command).BindByName = true;
       }
    }
```

Why is this?